# Is it possible to get chrome to export bookmarks (in HTML) with higher res favicons?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks, favicon

When I export bookmarks from chrome it's always as an HTML with favicon data. Something along the lines of `ICON="data:image/png;base64,<base64 code here>"`
However, when I decode the base64 code in the html, I always get back a 16x16 favicon. Is it possible to get chrome to return higher res favicons? Firefox bookmark exports always return 192x192 favicons.

If Firefox can return lower res favicons I'd also like to hear about it. Basically any size changing of these exports.